# IIS URL re-write

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have an intranet hosted on an IIS server (Windows Server 2016) which I want to run over https.  On our internal web server I have set up a Host (A) record:

Host - intranet
FQDN - intranet.mydomain.co.uk
IP address - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I have applied a certificate to the IIS server and set up the bindings and it loads fine.  However previously people could access the intranet through an Alias (CNAME) record - i.e. http://intranet
and I am worried that they will grumble about the longer URL.

Is there a way of setting something up so if you type in https://intranet then what you are seeing is https://intranet.mydomain.co.uk and not get any certificate errors.  I am wondering if I can do something with DNS, URL masking or URL re-write.

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: That's not doable unless your server certificate covers both https://intranet and https://intranet.mydomain.co.uk, or you have two separate certificates for each.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in the end by installing URL Rewrite on IIS then adding a rule:

1. Requested URL - matches the pattern
2. Using - regular expressions
3. Pattern - .*
4. Ignore case - ticked
5. Conditions - {HTTP_HOST} | Matches the Pattern | intranet
6. Action type - redirect
7. Redirect URL - https://intranet.mydomain.co.uk/{R:0}
8. Append query string - ticked
9. Redirect type - permanent (301)